# What does TextDirection really do in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, right-to-left, text-rendering, left-to-right

What difference does using TextDirection make. It's required all over the place in Flutter but the purpose isn't clear.

For example, given the following code:

```
const text = 'Hello';
final textSpan = const TextSpan(
  text: text,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.black),
);

final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter()
  ..textDirection = TextDirection.ltr
  ..text = textSpan
  ..layout();
textPainter.paint(canvas, Offset(0, 0));
```

The text direction is set to `TextDirection.ltr`. This prints `Hello`.

However, setting the text direction to `TextDirection.rtl` doesn't give `olleH`. It's still `Hello`. So what is the purpose of `TextDirection`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextDirection` doesn't change the order of characters within left-to-right (LTR) text like English or Russian. Neither does it change the order of characters within right-to-left (RTL) text like Arabic or Hebrew.

What `TextDirection` does is changes the order blocks of LTR and RTL text when they occur in the same string, that is, as bidirectional text.

You can see this in the following example:

```
const text = 'Hello שלום';
```

That string contains both LTR text (Hello) and also RTL text (שלום). The LTR text comes at the beginning of the string. So when you are in an LTR environment `Hello` should be painted on the left (first) and `שלום` on the right (last).

Indeed, you can observe this to be true:

```dart
const text = 'Hello שלום';
final textSpan = const TextSpan(
  text: text,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.black),
);
final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter()
  ..textDirection = TextDirection.ltr  //       <-- LTR
  ..text = textSpan
  ..layout();
textPainter.paint(canvas, Offset(0, 0));
```

This results in:

[image]

But change the direction to `TextDirection.rtl` and you'll get the following result:

[image]

The `Hello` is still first but since the environment is RTL now, this means first is on the right. The `שלום` is still last but now last is on the left. Interestingly, the space is maintained between them.